# SharePoint SPServices autocomplete not working for a column

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spservices

I have a working jQuery SPServices code for a column *Description* in a list. The problem is, that when I try to get the data from another column, *Project Item*, with the same code, nothing happens. Also, when I try to put the code for the both columns, the code does not work for any. Both columns are of *Single line of text* type. The code is following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('ctl00_m_g_b3f08547_27a4_484c_938a_f92864c47b7a_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl').title = 'Test';

        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({ 
            sourceList: "Projects",
            sourceColumn: "Project Item",
            columnName: "Test",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 2,
            slideDownSpeed: 50,
            debug: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs for the autocomplete function. The sourceColumn name needs to be the StaticName for the column, which in this case is likely to be Project_x0020_Item.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and a very big thank you for writing the library itself! It is a big help!

Just to clarify if a SP beginner such as myself stumbles upon this:
The sourceColumn internal (Static) name can be found by going to List Settings > Edit Column > and from there, search for Field= in the page URL as shown [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/66059/16290).